# Can webkit's vertical scroll behaviour be disabled temporarily on Android 4.0.4?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webkit

I have 2 horizontal sliders on a mobile web page (This is a mobile web application, not an App). On some android devices with smaller screens (or perhaps just different height/width ratios), just touching the screen activates the vertical scrolling behaviour of the device/browser. This interferes with the ability to use the horizontal sliders - the browser 'thinks' the user wants to scroll up and down but actually they need to drag a slider handle left and right.

Is there a way to prevent the vertical scrolling behaviour on a touch event within a slider handle and then have it renabled on touch up? Does the Webkit stock browser on Android 4.0.4 support this?

Comment: I can't say for sure about vertical scrolling but if horizontal scrolling works (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/#carousel-image-text-horizontal) which it does on ICS, I think its a safe bet that vertical scrolling would work in the same way.